# nodejs (express) installation for windows not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am new to nodejs and iam install nodejs with the help of simple setup and now i am trying to install framework  **express** where the node js was installed. I am getting only express-generator@4.13.1  but the path was shoing in wrong direction `C:\users...\AppData` i guess the installation should be inside node. Can some body help me what i am doing wrong and when i am trying to run simple express code i am getting below error.

Here is the code.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('hello world')
})
app.listen(8080)
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks & Regards

Comment: did u install express as a dependency to your app?

Comment: @war1oc thanks for the reply could you please explain what you mean dependency here

Comment: i meant the npm dependencies, can you show ur package.json file?

Comment: I have one more query here after you asking package.json do i have to install package.json before ??

Comment: are you following these steps?http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: @Yerken thank you so much for the link iam actually looking for the steps to install node and NPM (Express) / other tool

Comment: @Yerken Could you please tell me where i have to install this express in this path or C:\Program Files\nodejs or .... ?

Comment: because the one which i have installed it shows the path as C:\Users\Mahadevan\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: let me put it as an answer

Comment: `npm install express-generator -g` can be run anywhere, it makes no difference. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP mentioned he is using express generator. http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

The installation requires to run `npm install express-generator -g`. 
Note the usage of `-g` - which means that the express generator will be installed globally. `express` command will be exposed to command prompt (terminal in UNIX) and can be used to create node-express project scaffolds

So after running this command u need to create a project using `express-generator`. Go to the folder/directory where u want to keep ur project. As I can see you use windows, so you can go to `C:\Users\dude\`.

Now run this command to create a scaffold of the project named `my-cool-project` using `express-generator`.

`express my-cool-project`

After this is done your project template is created, **but** dependencies are not yet installed. You can see `package.json` in the project folder, those contain all dependencies specific for your project and those need be installed in your project directory. For that just run the following command
`npm install`

What this does is - reading your `package.json` and install whatever dependency are indicated there. After it is done you can start your app.

**Note** that there is no `-g` flag in `npm install`, which indicates that your installing packages from `package.json` and those will be applied only to the modules in your project.

**Another note** You don't have to modify the package.json and run `npm install` every time you want to add new dependencies. You can simply run 
`npm install --save my-new-dependency` 
This will install the dependencies in your project and `--save` flag will update your package.json with new dependencies for the sake of making your project usable by other people who want to install all the dependencies from package.json without surprises.

Comment: if i try to run the file node example.js i am still getting error cannot find module

i am trying running from the path E:\web_development\node> node example.js do i want to create the folder inside nodejs installation

Comment: have u run `npm install` ?

Comment: yes i install npm and i checked $ express -h i am getting the options and $express myapp

Comment: when u run `express myapp` it shoud generate a new folder in `E:\web_development\node\myapp`, u need to run `npm install` from there

Comment: and then start ur app from there too

Comment: but my mistaken i have installed npm in C Drive itselft is that possisble to remove from there or is that possible to reinstall in this drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101524/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-yerken).